# RavenDB running more slowly when using authorization

Tags: ravendb

I recently upgraded RavenDB from build 573 to 960. There is a noticeable slow-down when saving  documents. The only change I made when upgrading was to add this line to Raven.Server.exe.config:

```
<add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredUsers" value="d1\PrestoDatabaseUser;d2\userName"/>
```

Well, I also changed AnonymousAccess from All to Get.

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get"/>
```

1. Is there a slowness issue with build 960?
2. Is there anything new to be done when upgrading to build 960, other than replacing the binaries?
3. Does authorization (like shown above) cause RavenDB to run more slowly?
4. Any other ideas?

**Edit - This Worked**

I just tried this (only the third line is new):

```
documentStore.ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb";
documentStore.Initialize();
documentStore.JsonRequestFactory.ConfigureRequest += (sender, e) => ((HttpWebRequest)e.Request).PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't matter, no.
What is likely to have happened is that you are now actually doing authentication when saving.
Use:

```
docStore.JsonRequestFactory.ConfigureRequest += (sender, e) => ((HttpWebRequest)e.Request).PreAuthenticate = true;
```

And see if that helps

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and got an object reference error. I altered my question to show the details. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I got it. I needed to do this first: `documentStore.Initialize()`.